# I need help deploying a springboot application in heroku

Tags: spring, spring-boot, heroku, deployment, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to deploy a spring boot application in Heroku for production, this is my first time deploying a backend to production but the pricing page is confusing me, because there's a lot of different types to choose from, like the dyno, Heroku Postgres etc., Am I able to create a live database where i can store data which is not local if i only choose Heroku basic dyno, or do i have to get also the Heroku Postgres to do that, if so then what is the benefit or why should i get the dyno.